# "Error: validateAndFixActivity(): missing activity type."

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I've created a Teams bot using the 'Post messages to Teams' template from VS Code Teams Toolkit plug v4.1.3.

After provisioning and deploying it to Azure, sending a POST request to it results in a `400 Bad Request` with the following response:

`"Error: validateAndFixActivity(): missing activity type."`

It works fine if I run it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several APIs for a 'Post messages to Teams' app, and please make sure you are sending POST to '**/api/notification**', e.g.,

POST to *https://{your-azure-host}.azurewebsites.net/**api/notification***

In addition, the `400 Bad Request` may be returned by another API **/api/messages** which is used for Bot Framework Connection.